# Spring reactive with dynamic producers

Tags: java, spring, reactive

I have reacently started to use reactive thinking together with java and Spring.

Would it be possible create a scenario where you have a dynamic number of producers? Im developing a product that listen to a particular hardware for events and It would be awsome if I could add (and possibly remove) listening to devices dynamicaly A,B...Z without ending the stream.

I imagine a something like:

```
@GetMapping("/")
public Flux<HardwareEvent> void test() {
  return Flux.merge(
    listenHardware(A),
    listenHardware(B)
  );
}

Flux<HardwareEvent> listenHardware(HardwareId id); // produced indefinite stream of events
```

Where you somehow could inject new producers to the merge dynamically without stopping the stream.

Is this possible?

If someone could point me to (or post) an example it would be awesome.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You might need some glue code in the middle, but this looks like a good use case for [Subjects](https://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html)

Instead of having a "regular" `Observable`, you'd have a `Subject` that you're seeing as an Observable. Good thing of `Subject`s is that you can emit new values on demand so you could do something like

```
Subject<Value> s = ...;
Observable<Value> getObservable() {
  return s;
}

void addSource(Observable<Value> obs) {
  obs.subscribe(v -> s.emit(s))
}
```

Notice that it's pseudocode and will probably not compile as is

Take a look to the [`Subject` docs](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html) to see which one fits your needs better

Comment: Interesting - However, I'm not sure Springs flavor of reactive supports Subjects or maby its just named something else (Subject is a bit tricky to google ;))

Comment: That's why I included links to the documentation. Spring webflux supports RxJava as well

Comment: oh - ok, Sorry didnt know that. As mentined my Im a reactive-newbie. Thanks for you time anyway :)